# Save, update, get and sanitize post meta as HTML not plain

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

My post meta always is plain text HTML striped from it

I need to Save, update, get and sanitize post meta as HTML not plain

here is all my related code to this post meta filed

Retrieve from database

`$food_excerpt = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'food_excerpt', true );`

set default value

`if( empty( $food_excerpt ) ) $food_excerpt = '';`

the filed on the admin

```
$content = $food_excerpt;
wp_editor( $content, 'food_excerpt', $settings = array('textarea_rows'=> '10') );
```

Sanitize

`$food_new_excerpt = isset( $_POST[ 'food_excerpt' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'food_excerpt' ] ) : '';`

Update

`update_post_meta( $post_id, 'food_excerpt', $food_new_excerpt );`

Comment: what doesn't work as you want with this code ?

Comment: The `sanitize_text_field` function you're using strips all HTML. So, you'll need to sanitize it a different way. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/

Comment: @WebElaine kindly put your answer with the correct code

Comment: You can use WP's `wp_kses` or perform your own sanitization. You'll have to decide which approach works best for your situation. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses

Comment: my experience about sanitize is very little , could you please  put an answer with correct code